# REST API only in Express getting 'Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided'

Tags: node.js, express

I used the express starter project to get started then removed all the jade aspects as I'm just using this as a ReSTful api and don't care about views.  I'm new to the stack so just trying to get some basic stuff setup.

For GET things work fine and get back my data. When I add a post route per the examples I've seen I get the error "Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided".  I can tell from my console.log that the route never gets hit.

I'm unclear why GET is working but POST appears to want to return a view and never reaches my post route.

```
router.route('/')
.get(function (req, res, next) {

    User.find(query, (err, users) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json([{
                id: 1,
                username: "samsepi0l"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                username: "D0loresH4ze"
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                username: "freddy"
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                username: "mac"
            }
            ]);
            // res.json(users);
        }
    });
}).post(function (req, res) {
    console.log('test');
    var user = new User(req.body);
    user.save();
    res.status(201).send(user);
});
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3001);

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/api/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

The `res.render` function is called, which tries to render a view. This doesn’t work because you removed the code for rendering views.

If you replace `res.render('error')` with `res.send()`, it will just send a status code without any content. This function can also be used to [send custom error responses](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.send).

Alternatively, you can send the actual error back to the client by simply calling `next(err)`. This will invoke the default error handler in Express, which will give you the error message in the response including the stack trace. This also makes it easier to debug your application.

***Note***: When using the default error handler, make sure you set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable to `"production"` when deploying your app to a production environment to avoid showing the stack traces to your users.

Comment: Thanks, turned out I had an exception being thrown.  Once I replaced render with send I was able to send back the error, see the problem and address it.